# Xib view controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to use [this repository](http://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) from Github and to use it you must have a xib file whether it's in your storyboard or not and I wanted to know how I can do to have my view controllers acting like xib but in my storyboard.

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough but just tell me in the comments and I'll try my best to be clearer.

Kindest regards,

Comment: I had a quick look and it seems you simply need to create a new view controller. When you create that just tick the check mark so XCode creates ths XIB along with the controller.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I don't want to use xib... I would have my viewController acting like a xib but in my storyboard,

Comment: Then just use the controller. The XIB is only used in the according load method where it reads the XIB and assigns the single GUI objects. You can do that manually in the init yourself.

Comment: @ThomasKilianI'm sorry I'm a beginner (and only 14 :)) so could you add an answer with some code or something like that ? Because I'm not sure of what you say... Thanks :)

Comment: Well, actually no. You need to post your code and people here will have a look what might be wrong. But you will not get any code here (except you find someone having a good day). So maybe you post (excerpts) what you did so far and tell what happened where (error/unexpected behavior). Good luck anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is in your project select `New File` from the file menu or by right clicking in your file navigator. On the popupWindow select iOS on the left (This will let you see all the options) find the "View Option".

[image]

and this will create a View.Xib file. This is just the UI file for a view.

[image]